# Facebook vs 3rd party link clicks

Tags: php, mysql, facebook

I am creating a 3rd party tracker which demands that i keep record of clicks on my links.

What I am doing is: getting the users to my server, checking the ips and user agents and sending them to destination for which they have clicked. From ips and user agents I detect bots from "crawler-detect api" and check for duplicate ips.
After checking the conditions +1 the counter for that particular link.

PROBLEM:
when I redirect traffic from facebook,my counter/tracker gives almost 3.1 times more clicks then the facebook tracker. What could be the possible reasons for that?

(I have already checks for bos and duplicate ips)

Comment: Likely checking for phishing and spam content.  This sort of tracking is never 100% accurate... I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: I have blocked crawlers, spiders and bots to some extent using the mentioned library.... it should be accurate if people intend to use it commercially........ difference shouldnt be as large as 3.1 times....

Comment: What makes you think you can actually block crawlers, spiders, and bots?  (You can't.)  Complete accuracy is impossible.  It doesn't matter what people intend to do, you can't track something that is impossible to accurately track.  The point of such analytics is to analyze trends.  Exact numbers aren't typically worth your time.  In any case, if you wanted us to help you figure out what sort of traffic might be discardable, you should have posted the full request data for a sample of your traffic.  Not that it matters... as soon as a bot is updated, it may look different.

Comment: you are right I guess.... but how do pay per click (trackers) do it? there are a lot of systems available that actually monitor clicks and distinguish humans from bots etc to achieve the purpose. If they are doing it there must be a way.
I was hoping for some checks and validations I may be missing. In that regard your help would be really appreciated. :)

Comment: They don't.  False clicks, bots, etc., get through all the time.  The best you can do is set up some tooling around monitoring logs, identify suspicious behavior, block it, and apply updates retroactively.  (You might come in one day and realize that for the last 3 hours, someone has snuck through your filtering.  Now you need to get to update those numbers.  Maybe last night, Facebook did an update to its link checker and now its behavior looks different and is no longer being filtered.  Time to update and apply retroactively.)

Comment: The truth is, a best effort approach here is usually good enough.

Comment: Okay I will apply the monitoring and backtracking on logs. Thank you for help.......